# How to make a function as a change?

Tags: vimscript

I can define a vimscript function, for example

```
function GoUp()
    while line(".") > 1 && (strlen(getline(".")) < col(".") || getline(".")[col(".") - 1] =~ '\s') 
        norm k
    endwhile
endfunction
```

and then assign a shortcut to it

```
nnoremap gU :call GoUp()<CR>
```

, so `gU` will go up until hit a non-space character.

However, such `gU` can't be repeated by pressing dot (`.`) as it is only movement, not a change.

Is there a way to walk around it? for example, set a flag in the function to "cheat" the Vim to take it as a change, or, make it possible to be repeated by `n`?

Comment: Stating the obvious: creating a mapping for `gU` shadows the very useful functionality to convert text to uppercase.

Comment: @Friedrich indeed, though it's not to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your particular function correctly, the following command searches backwards for a non-space character in the same column as the cursor:

```
?\%.c\S
```

This would be repeatable with `n`.

Comment: just to be clear, from normal mode, shall i type `:` or `/` before I type `?\%.c\S`, or shall i directly start with `?\%.c\S`? i tried (in windows gVim) but hit error "E867: (NFA) Unknown operator '\%.'"

Comment: None of them, you have to type directly `?` which search backward as opposed to `/` that search forward.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt still, I got error messages E867: (NFA) Unknown operator '\%.' and E383: Invalid search string: \%.c\S ...

Comment: Then you are not doing it correctly: `nnoremap <key> ?\%.c\S<CR>`.

Comment: What is the Vim version that you are using (`:version`)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt i'm using VIM 8.2.12 in windows 10 22H2, is this too old?

Comment: Indeed the operator `\%.c` has been introduced during the 8.2 live. It is present at the end of the 8.2 live but not with 8.2.1 (I don't know yet when exactly it has been introduced).

Comment: Looking at the GitHub repository of Vim I believe the feature has been introduced in version 8.2.3110 (on 5th of July 2021).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thank you, i installed vim 9.1 and now it's there :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)